# Simple string comparison not working! Frustration ensues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot seem to figure out why this comparison is not working:

```
if params[:password].to_s == params[:conf_password].to_s
  #do something
else
  #do something else
```

The result is always false, executing the else block... Anyone know why?

Edit: Checking the output shows that the two parameters are identical. "password" is collected using a 'form_for' and "conf_password" from a password_field_tag.

If "conf_password" is included in the 'form_for' a no such method error is thrown, because there is no column conf_password in the model. Perhaps there is a better way of collecting this param, which may solve the issue.

some log output regarding params.

```
PARAMS: {"password"=>"1234567", "company"=>"company1", "companykey"=>"ckey2"}, "conf_password"=>"1234567",
```

Code to get these values

```
<tr> <td> <%= label_tag(:password, "Password") %> </td> <td> <%= f.password_field :password %> </td> </tr>

<tr> <td> <%= label_tag(:conf_password, "Confirm Password") %> </td> <td> <%= password_field_tag(:conf_password) %> </td> </tr>
```

Comment: How about showing us what those two values actually are?

Comment: And you have created output for both `params[:password]` and `params[:conf_password]` not just for params in general? From the laymans perspective the password seems to be inside a hash and shouldn't be accessed the same the :conf_password

Comment: how can I output that? I am unfamiliar with Rails.logger. Its in a create method, so there is no associated view to do it that way. I am currently doing this: Rails.logger.debug("PARAMS: #{params.inspect}"). I haven't hashed the password yet(unless something is done automatically for me). I am putting that code in the model once I get this error resolved.

Comment: `Rails.logger.debug("'#{params[:password]}' vs. '#{params[:conf_password]}'")` should work then?

Comment: Ok, when I use that, password shows up as an empty string?!  '' vs. '1234567'. I have edited the original post to include the code that obtains these two parameters. I do not see any error! Note, when I change the == to !=, these params are written to the database. Password is not an empty string then, but is 1234567

Comment: I assume that because the `:password` is in a hash, you should use `params[:<something>[:password]]` where `<something>` is the container specified in `f`. See http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters. Better link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html. I will add and answer containing this discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you should not be accessing `:password` and `:conf_password` the same way as the `:password` parameter is within a hash while `:conf_password` is not.

When you declare the form_for you also define the hash that contains the `:password` and you have to access the `:password`-parameter with `new Object(params[:object]).password`. You are able to access the parameter with `params[:object][:password]` as well.

Untested example form based on copy-paste coding

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />

  <%= f.label :password %>:
  <%= f.text_field :password %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Untested example controller based on deduction not knowledge

```
if Person.create(params[:person]).password == 'foobar'
   # go on
else 
   # fail
end
```

For more though out description see the API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: Trying that moves me to the error: undefined method `password'. I added a method password that just returns params[:password] (which probably defeats the point) but even doing that was to no avail. I am mind boggled. Its only my second day with ruby on rails though, so..

Comment: BINGO, using params[:object][:password] did the trick. You're a genius. Thanks so much!